# semver increment in shell script

Tags: sh, parameter-expansion

I am trying to implement a solution to increment a version. Here's what I have come up with:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -x

VAR=1.0.1 # retrieved from Gitlab API

case $1 in
patch)
    TAG=${VAR%.*}.$((${VAR##*.} + 1))
    ;;

major)
    TAG=$((${VAR%%.*} + 1)).0.0
    ;;

*)
    tmp=${VAR%.*}
    minor=${tmp#*.}
    TAG=${VAR%%.*}.$((minor + 1)).0
    ;;
esac

echo $TAG
```

`major` & `patch` work as expected; however, I'm facing problems incrementing `minor`.

When bumping `1.0.1`, the minor should be `1.1.0`; however, my code produces `1.2.0`. What am I doing wrong?

Some more info, the script is executed inside a GitlabCI pipeline.

Edit: Updated the code with the suggested answer from @jhnc

Comment: I suggest to take a look at: `var=1.2.3; IFS="." read a b c <<< "$var"; echo "$a $b $c"`

Comment: Unfortunately can't use IFS 
`/bin/sh: script.sh: line 12: syntax error: unexpected redirection`

Comment: You tagged your question with `bash` and not with `sh`.

Comment: @hdhruna, ...to be clear: that's like tagging for C++ but then requiring answers to work with a C compiler. They're two different languages, and not compatible. (If your script is run with `sh yourscript`, that means it's parsed and executed as a sh script, not a bash script, even if it _does_ start with `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: @hdhruna, ...also, `IFS` works fine with `sh`. It's `<<<` -- not `IFS` -- that's bash-only syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation for incrementing minor is:

```
TAG=${VAR%%.*}.$((${VAR##*.} + 1)).0
```

However, `${VAR##*.}` gives the patch value, not the minor value, and thus your incorrect result.

To extract minor, you can use a temporary variable:

```
tmp=${VAR%.*}
minor=${tmp#*.}
TAG=${VAR%%.*}.$((minor + 1)).0
```

Alternatively, it may be more readable to set `IFS` and split the string on dots:

```
TAG=$(
   echo "$VAR" | while IFS=. read major minor patch; do
       # add sanity-checks here
       case "$1" in
          patch)
             echo "$major.$minor.$((patch+1))"
             ;;
          major)
             echo "$((major+1).0.0"
             ;;
          minor|*)
             echo "$major.$((minor+1)).0" 
             ;;
       esac
   done
)
```

You should probably add sanity-checks to ensure `VAR` is actually of form "digits dot digits dot digits".

Comment: I think I prefer KamilCuk's IFS/<< method to mine here. There's only one variable to split, so using a while loop feels wrong and the subshell/echo malarkey adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @jhnc, ...what _is_ the purpose of the `while` loop, btw? I'd think you could write `echo "$VAR" | { IFS=. read major minor patch; case "$1" in ...;; esac; }`, with no `while`, though there is indeed still subshell overhead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I rarely (never?) use `read` for just one line and so I typed a `while` loop on autopilot :-) Didn't even realise until I saw the other answer.

Answer (score 9):

I would just:

```
#!/bin/sh

var=1.0.1
IFS=. read -r version minor patch <<EOF
$var
EOF

case "$1" in
patch) tag="$version.$minor.$((patch+1))"; ;;
major) tag="$((version+1)).0.0"; ;;
*)     tag="$version.$((minor+1)).0"; ;;
esac

echo $tag
```

Works on alpine with ash.

Comment: @KamilCuk, since there were no examples, that was one of the reasons I chose to write the code this way.